# OracleCommand StoredProcedure returning "null" instead of DBNull

Tags: vb.net, string, oracle, odp.net, oraclecommand

I have a stored procedure that in certain situations returns null. When I `ToString()` the null it returns "null" as a string instead of an empty string, however if I don't use the `.ToString()` method it causes an error.

```
Public Function ReturnValue(ByVal lngId As Long) As String
    Dim adoCmd As New OracleCommand
    Dim strReturn As String = ""

    With adoCmd

        .CommandText = "BUS_TEST.ReturnValue"
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        .Parameters.Add("return", OracleDbType.Char, 256, strReturn, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)
        .Parameters.Add("lngId", OracleDbType.Double, lngId, ParameterDirection.Input)
    End With

    objSalUtil.ExecFunc(ocEWBConnection, adoCmd, "ReturnValue")

    Return adoCmd.Parameters(0).Value.ToString

End Function
```

The above code returns "null"

```
Public Function ReturnValue(ByVal lngId As Long) As String
    Dim adoCmd As New OracleCommand
    Dim strReturn As String = ""

    With adoCmd

        .CommandText = "BUS_TEST.ReturnValue"
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        .Parameters.Add("return", OracleDbType.Char, 256, strReturn, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)
        .Parameters.Add("lngId", OracleDbType.Double, lngId, ParameterDirection.Input)
    End With

    objSalUtil.ExecFunc(ocEWBConnection, adoCmd, "ReturnValue")

    Return adoCmd.Parameters(0).Value

End Function
```

The above code causes an InvalidCastException: Conversion from type 'OracleString' to type 'String' is not valid.

```
Public Function ReturnValue(ByVal lngId As Long) As String
    Dim adoCmd As New OracleCommand
    Dim strReturn As String = ""

    With adoCmd

        .CommandText = "BUS_TEST.ReturnValue"
        .CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

        .Parameters.Add("return", OracleDbType.Char, 256, strReturn, ParameterDirection.ReturnValue)
        .Parameters.Add("lngId", OracleDbType.Double, lngId, ParameterDirection.Input)
    End With

    objSalUtil.ExecFunc(ocEWBConnection, adoCmd, "ReturnValue")

    Return strReturn

End Function
```

And lastly, the above code returns a proper empty string, however it does so in all cases, regardless of whether something should have been returned or not.

I've used stored procedures like this a lot in the past, however they've always returned a value in all cases. I'm not quite sure how to handle this null. I'd prefer to not check for a string containing "null" first, as this is a little hacky, and I'd like to know for the future what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Forgot to mention that I've tried this with OracleDbType.Varchar2 as well, that was the primary way I tested it.

Comment: So you want to return an empty string if the return value is null or DbNull.Value?

Comment: Yes, ideally I'd like to convert it to an empty string in some way. I have a procedure that I call for things that can be DBNull when returned from a select statement, that works well. The problem is this field, the application doesn't see as DBNull, or Nothing, it sees it as a value it can't understand, unless I call .toString, then it sees it as "null"

Comment: Can you add the code for the stored procedure?

Comment: I cannot, outside of my realm. I can tell you the exact same stored procedure works correctly in vb6

Comment: Are you using ODP.NET?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think, you're using ODP.NET. In this case, instead of this

```
Return adoCmd.Parameters(0).Value
```

You do this

```
Dim oraStr As OracleString = CType(adoCmd.Parameters(0).Value, OracleString)
Return oraStr.Value ' return .net string
```

What happening is, this `adoCmd.Parameters(0).Value` returns you `Oracle null`. If you cast your return value into Oracle Type, now you can access .Net-typed value. when you use `adoCmd.Parameters(0).Value.ToString()` you get Oracle implementation of `ToString`, which simply returns some word `null`.

This is something to remember when you use odp.net Oracle parameters, Stored Procedure or parametrized query with return values - doesn't matter, like here

```
Dim sql as String = "insert into table ...) returning fld1 into :1"
```

> **Interesting Observation:** In `SqlClient` this is illegal `Parameters(0).Value = Nothing`. It wants `DBNull.Value`. In ODP.NET is not a problem. It takes any - `Nothing` or/and `DBNull.Value`

When you use `OracleReader`, especially through `IDataReader` - this is not a problem. `Reader("fld1")` will return .net type.

```
Dim r As IdataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader...
Dim i As Integer = reader("fld1")
```

Where you need to be careful is in matching Oracle DB Type to .NET. Problem is, they don't match. If you declare table field `Number(9)` it will return .net `Integer` but `Number(9)` not large enough to fit `Integer.MaxValue`. If you declare table field `Number(10)`, `Reader("fld1")` will return `Long`. So, .net `Integer` falls somewhere between `Number(9)` and `Number(10)`. You need to use convert

```
 Dim i As Integer = convert.ToInt32(reader("fld1"))
```

Answer (score 0):

It turns out adding this line to between the two parameters fixed the problem.

```
adoCmd.Parameters(0).DbType = DbType.String
```